# file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: laravel-5

I am develope a laravel app. I go to the route folder myapp/routes/web.php on serve and register a new route as follows:

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

when i enter https://chanvay.store/linkstorage and hit enter.
Error appeared

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/chanvays/domains/chanvay.store/public_html/public/storage) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/chanvays/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php81/lib/php/)
Anybody help me ?

Anybody help me fix this issue ?
I can not comman php artisan storage:link on serve.

Comment: http://www.mywebsite.com/linkstorage doesn't show that error. Also, why not run the command on the shell? Also, keep in mind that Laravel 5 is pretty outdated and should no longer be used

Comment: sorry the correct link is https://chanvay.store/linkstorage

Comment: Please check the configuration of your application. Such messages should never be shown in production mode, especially when they also include your database credentials

Comment: everything is ok at local, but not working on server. you can hit www.chanvay.store and see all image not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.